# tough mysql query, need words in common between users

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've following mysql query:

```
SELECT u.name_surname, 
       u.avatar,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT w.word ORDER BY w.word ASC) AS asker_words,
       (a.friend_id) AS asker_id
FROM users u
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT f1.asker_user_id AS friend_id
    FROM friends AS f1 
    LEFT JOIN friends AS f2
        ON f1.asked_user_id = f2.asker_user_id
        AND f1.asker_user_id = f2.asked_user_id   
    WHERE f1.status = 1 AND f2.status IS NULL
    AND f1.asked_user_id = :user_id
) a ON a.friend_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN connections c ON u.id = c.user_id
LEFT JOIN words_en w ON w.id = c.word_id
        WHERE c.invisible <> 1
          AND c.deleted <> 1
GROUP BY 1
```

What it does is essentially provide me with friend requests targeted to current user (asked_user_id).

```
Friends table is simple:
id | asker_user_id | asked_user_id | status | created
```

Query above gives me users who initiated friend request with current user, along with the words asker user has under his account.

I'm having two problems, I cannot resolve.

1) This query grabs all words from asker user. Instead I would like to grab words that asker and asked have in common/same minus ones set invisible or deleted.

2) Friend request query should grab row even if users have no words in common. Atm, when asker user has no words under his account request disappears.

3) order by amount of words in common.

SQLfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b158f/1

please note in the results, word1 word2 are in common, but welcome is not in common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand your 2nd problem statement.  Could you give an example in SQLfiddle of this data? Otherwise, see this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13979/17.  In the new `LEFT JOIN` clause, the hard coded 1 should be the same as the 1 from the `INNER JOIN` clause.:

```
SELECT u.name_surname, 
       u.avatar,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT w.word ORDER BY w.word ASC) AS asker_words,
       (a.friend_id) AS asker_id
       ,COUNT(w.id) AS WordCount
FROM users u
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT f1.asker_user_id AS friend_id
    FROM friends AS f1 
    LEFT JOIN friends AS f2
        ON f1.asked_user_id = f2.asker_user_id
        AND f1.asker_user_id = f2.asked_user_id   
    WHERE f1.status = 1 AND f2.status IS NULL
    AND f1.asked_user_id = 1
) a ON a.friend_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN connections c 
  ON u.id = c.user_id
    AND c.invisible <> 1
    AND c.deleted <> 1
LEFT JOIN connections c2
  ON c2.word_id = c.word_id
    AND c2.user_id = 1
    AND c2.invisible <> 1
    AND c2.deleted <> 1
LEFT JOIN words_en w 
  ON w.id = c2.word_id
GROUP BY u.name_surname
ORDER BY WordCount DESC;
```

Comment: Hi, can you please take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456030/creating-friends-timeline-similar-to-facebook-mysql-query